# Receiving a 505 error in AWS Glue job during execution

Tags: pyspark, etl, aws-glue, http-status-code-503

I have scheduled a job on AWS Glue. Initially I was getting a 503 Error, saying driver is getting too many requests .I later added prefixes and it worked fine. But now the job is taking too long to complete execution(for a small file of 200mb zip file, its took 5hrs and still running). I have added the code below, please can anyone suggest for needed code modifications.

```
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,broadcast

#create a dataframe of base objects - reporting_entity_name, reporting_entity_type, version, last_updated_on
#using the output of preprocessing step

base_df = spark.read.json('s3://yourbucket03/Atena/preprocessed/base/')

#create a dataframe over provider_references objects using the output of preprocessing step
prvd_df = spark.read.json('s3://yourbucket03/Atena/preprocessed/provider_references/')

#cross join dataframe of base objects with dataframe of provider_references 
prvd_df = prvd_df.crossJoin(broadcast(base_df))

#create a dataframe over in_network objects using the output of preprocessing step
in_ntwrk_df = spark.read.json('s3://yourbucket03/Atena/preprocessed/in_network/')

#unnest and flatten negotiated_rates and provider_references from in_network objects
in_ntwrk_df2 = in_ntwrk_df.select(
 in_ntwrk_df.billing_code, in_ntwrk_df.billing_code_type, in_ntwrk_df.billing_code_type_version,
  in_ntwrk_df.description, in_ntwrk_df.name,
 explode(in_ntwrk_df.negotiated_rates).alias('exploded_negotiated_rates'),
 in_ntwrk_df.negotiation_arrangement)


in_ntwrk_df3 = in_ntwrk_df2.select(
 in_ntwrk_df2.billing_code, in_ntwrk_df2.billing_code_type, in_ntwrk_df2.billing_code_type_version,
 in_ntwrk_df2.description, in_ntwrk_df2.name,
 in_ntwrk_df2.exploded_negotiated_rates.negotiated_prices.alias(
 'exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices'),
 explode(in_ntwrk_df2.exploded_negotiated_rates.provider_references).alias(
 'exploded_negotiated_rates_provider_references'),
 in_ntwrk_df2.negotiation_arrangement)

#join the exploded in_network dataframe with provider_references dataframe
jdf = prvd_df.join(
 in_ntwrk_df3,
 prvd_df.provider_group_id == in_ntwrk_df3.exploded_negotiated_rates_provider_references,"fullouter")

#un-nest and flatten attributes from rest of the nested arrays.
jdf2 = jdf.select(
 jdf.reporting_entity_name,jdf.reporting_entity_type,jdf.last_updated_on,jdf.version,
 jdf.provider_group_id, jdf.provider_groups, jdf.billing_code,
 jdf.billing_code_type, jdf.billing_code_type_version, 
 jdf.description, jdf.name,
 explode(jdf.exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices).alias(
 'exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices'),
 jdf.exploded_negotiated_rates_provider_references,
 jdf.negotiation_arrangement)

jdf3 = jdf2.select(
 jdf2.reporting_entity_name,jdf2.reporting_entity_type,jdf2.last_updated_on,jdf2.version,
 jdf2.provider_group_id,
 explode(jdf2.provider_groups).alias('exploded_provider_groups'),
 jdf2.billing_code, jdf2.billing_code_type, jdf2.billing_code_type_version,
  jdf2.description, jdf2.name,

 jdf2.exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices.billing_class.alias(
 'billing_class'),
 jdf2.exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices.billing_code_modifier.
 alias('billing_code_modifier'),
 jdf2.exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices.expiration_date.alias(
 'expiration_date'),
 jdf2.exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices.negotiated_rate.alias(
 'negotiated_rate'),
 jdf2.exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices.negotiated_type.alias(
 'negotiated_type'),
 jdf2.exploded_negotiated_rates_negotiated_prices.service_code.alias(
 'service_code'), jdf2.exploded_negotiated_rates_provider_references,
 jdf2.negotiation_arrangement)

jdf4 = jdf3.select(jdf3.reporting_entity_name,jdf3.reporting_entity_type,jdf3.last_updated_on,jdf3.version,
 jdf3.provider_group_id,
 explode(jdf3.exploded_provider_groups.npi).alias('npi'),
 jdf3.exploded_provider_groups.tin.type.alias('tin_type'),
 jdf3.exploded_provider_groups.tin.value.alias('tin'),
 jdf3.billing_code, jdf3.billing_code_type,
 jdf3.billing_code_type_version,
 jdf3.description, jdf3.name, 
 jdf3.billing_class, jdf3.billing_code_modifier,
 jdf3.expiration_date, jdf3.negotiated_rate,
 jdf3.negotiated_type, jdf3.service_code,
 jdf3.negotiation_arrangement)

#repartition by billing_code. 
#Repartition changes the distribution of data on spark cluster. 
#By repartition data we will avoid writing too many small files.
jdf5=jdf4.repartition("billing_code")
 
datasink_path = "s3://yourbucket03/Atena/processed/billing_code_npi/parquet/Atena_batched/"

#persist dataframe as parquet on S3 and catalog it
#Partition the data by billing_code. This enables analytical queries to skip data and improve performance of queries
#Data is also bucketed and sorted npi to improve query performance during analysis


# Define the batch size
batch_size = 20000

# Iterate over distinct billing_code_type values
for partition in jdf5.select("billing_code_type").distinct().collect():
    partition_value = partition.billing_code_type

    # Filter the data for the current partition
    partition_data = jdf5.filter(jdf5.billing_code_type == partition_value)

    # Generate a unique prefix for the current partition using billing_code_type
    prefix = f"prefix_{partition_value}/"

    # Count the total number of rows in the partition
    total_rows = partition_data.count()

    # Calculate the number of batches based on the batch size
    num_batches = (total_rows + batch_size - 1) // batch_size

    # Iterate over batches and write the data
    for batch_num in range(num_batches):
        # Calculate the starting and ending row index for the current batch
        start_index = batch_num * batch_size
        end_index = min((batch_num + 1) * batch_size, total_rows)

        # Get the data for the current batch
        batch_data = partition_data.limit(end_index - start_index).orderBy('npi')

        # Write the data with the specified prefix
        batch_data.write.format('parquet').mode("overwrite").option("path",       datasink_path).partitionBy('billing_code_type','billing_code').bucketBy(4, 'npi').saveAsTable('Atena_table', path=f"{datasink_path}/{prefix}")
```

Tried to run an ETL job on AWS Glue. But initially faced, 503 too many requests error.
Am expecting job to run without any error and want to reduce the duration of run.